# Django change BooleanField value after DateField expires

Tags: django, python-3.6

I would like to be able to automatically set suspended to False (if is True, of course) when end_suspension_date passes by (and therefore if it exists).

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    suspended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_suspension_date =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_suspension_date =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    # ... other fields
```

Is there any way to do this without third-party apps? I thought of defining a function inside the model (but I don't see much sense in doing so):

```
def end_suspension(self):
     if date.today() >= self.end_suspension_date:
          self.suspended = False 
          start_suspension_date = None
          end_suspension_date = None
      else:
          # do nothing...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need something like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to define a task that filters for end of suspension.

An alternative method I prefer is to replace  the `suspended` field with a property, because having a field that stores "is the user suspended" and a field that stores "when is the user no longer suspended" are redundant because we know the current date.

A more idiomatic would be calling it `is_suspended`, so:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def is_suspended(self):
        return date.today() < self.end_suspension_date
```

Then on login views permission checks etc just access `profile.is_suspended`.

Simple is better then complex :)

Aldi, beware of timezone. Rule of thumb: store UTC date instead of local date.

Comment: The side effect is that in my app profiles don't need a login, so if I check profile.is_suspended everytime I refresh the page it will add a lot of load time (if I have for example many Profile entries)

Comment: In terms of database reads there is no difference between the two solutions: if a Boolean field was used you would still need to hit the database to check if it was true or false

Comment: maybe I could set a control that call is_suspended() just once a day... Also thanks for the UTC suggestion, I'll check out how (if I can do i) to do it and update the post.

Comment: Candidly, I think you're overthinking it and are on the cusp of premature optimization. Start with the property and optimize it later if you see performance problems. Pro tip: you won't see performance problems here. Focus your time and effort on what matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it, like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    start_suspension_date =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_suspension_date =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    # ... other fields

    @property
    def suspended(self):
        return date.today() < self.end_suspension_date
```